# For loop in using fmincon function for different initial points

Tags: matlab, loops

I know this question is really too basic, but I am stuck since I am new to MATLAB. The problem is I do not know how to use **for-loop** to show three output of V in one run for different initial points.

I would like to have an output like the following:

V1 (first initial point)-----V2(second initial point)-----V3(third initial point)

This is my code:

```
%variables
ENG1=0.52;
ENG2 = [0.00139;0.00149;0.00122;0.00130;0.000866;0.000731;0.001002;0.001285];
ENG3 = zeros(8,1);
%6.2.2) minimization term
fun = @(V) abs(ENG1 - V'*ENG2);
%6.2.3) constrains:
Aeq = [ENG3';ones(1,8)];
beq = [0;1]; 
lb = zeros(8,1); %lower bound
ub = ones(8,1); %upper bound
V0 = rand(8,1);V0 = V0/sum(V0); %initial guess
options = optimset('Display', 'off'); %supressing extra unnecessary outputs.
for i=1:3
    V(i) = fmincon(fun,V0,[],[],Aeq,beq,lb,ub,[],options)
end
```

Comment: And what is the difference between your runs?

Comment: Different initial points (in my case 3 different intial points) produces different outputs. Since I need to run it three times, I thought it would be better to use a for loop, but I do not know how.

Comment: Have you tried writing the for loop? Or do you want other people to do it for you?

Comment: Sharing would be a great idea. It will make it much clearer what you want.

Comment: Yes, I added it in the code. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you store your different initial conditions as columns of a matrix you can do it in the following way:

```
V0 = rand(8,3); %3 columns of initial guesses
V0 = bsxfun(@rdivide, V0, sum(V0));
% V0 = V0./sum(V0); % similar to previous line, but only supported from R2016b
V = zeros(size(V0)); % preallocate memory for efficiency
for i=1:3
    V(:, i) = fmincon(fun,V0(:, i),[],[],Aeq,beq,lb,ub,[],options);
end
```

Note the use of the elementwise division (`./`) to normalise your initial guesses.

Note that `V(:, i)` selects all elements of column `i`.

See [this post](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2016/10/24/matlab-arithmetic-expands-in-r2016b/), for more information about the compatibility issue.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. It does work when I exclude the second initial guess ,i.e. V0=V0./sum(V0). Including second condition yields the following error:
Error using  ./ 
Matrix dimensions must agree.

Error in pltting (line 19)
V0 = rand(8,3);V0 = V0./sum(V0); %initial guess

Comment: I changed my solution to solve the compatibility issue

Comment: Thanks a lot... I tried the code, but I get 9 outputs, instead of three. Do you know why?

Comment: I do not understand what you mean. Is V a 8x9 matrix?

Comment: V, the output, is a 8x1 vector. I wanted to have three outputs for V, i.e. three 8x1 vectors. Right now, I get nine 8x1 vectors of V in the output window.

Comment: `V` should be a `8x3` matrix in which each column represents a solution. What is the dimension of your ` V0`?

Comment: The first initial value's dimension of V0 is 8x1. The second initial values' dimension of V0 is a scalar ( making sure summation of all elements in 8x1 V vector is unity).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145032/discussion-between-m7913d-and-mariam-salehi).